# Change selected XML file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, rss

I'm using the following piece of code to select and parse an XML file. Works great, but because I have 3 different XML files, I also have 3 different pages. It would make the application I'm building a lot faster if I could just replace the url to the XML file, instead of loading a completely new page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "rss/page1",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(xml) {
```

So, what I'm wondering is: Is it possible to change the url at `url:` with a simple jQuery event? 
In pseudo code it would be something like this:

```
<a id="index" href="#">Index</a>
<a id="page1" href="#">Page 1</a>
<a id="page2" href="#">Page 2</a>
```

If clicked on the `<a>` tag with `id="index"`, change `url: "rss/what_ever_it_is_now"` to `url: "rss/index"`

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just hook the click event on those elements to call the function with the appropriate file name?

http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/6rBjX/

Something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="parseButton" data-filename="rss/index">Index</a>
<a href="#" class="parseButton" data-filename="rss/page1">Page 1</a>
<a href="#" class="parseButton" data-filename="rss/page2">Page 2</a>

​function parseFile(fileName) {

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".parseButton").click(function(s,e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $(this).attr("data-filename"),
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
            ... 
       });
       e.preventDefault();
    }
    }​
```

By doing it this way, you can actually even add more links to parse additional XML files (should you ever need to) by simply changing the value in the `data-filename` attribute.  The line `e.preventDefault()` is used to prevent the page from reloading if you use an `a` tag.  Just remove it if you actually want to cause a page reload.

Comment: Hey Saluce,

Thanks for your answer, but in this situation buttons don't do the job. I will definitely keep this in mind though, if I ever can use buttons!

Comment: Note that you can still use `a` tags to do the job =)  Check my edits.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.lnk').click(function(){
      var pag = 'rss/'+ $(this).attr('id');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: pag,
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success: function(xml) {
      //....
    });
});
```

And the links:

```
<a class="lnk" id="index" href="#">Index</a>
<a class="lnk" id="page1" href="#">Page 1</a>
<a class="lnk" id="page2" href="#">Page 2</a>
```

Comment: Hi CoursesWeb,

I'm going to try this one now. Thank you for your solution. Just one small problem which you might be able to edit:
Because my rss-feeds are not stored simply in a folder called `rss/`, I should just change the id to the complete link and this to the following
`var pag = 'rss/'+ $(this).attr('id');` would become `var pag = $(this).attr('id');` and the id (for example) http://www.url.com/stored/index

Would that work? Or do you recommend I use a similar system with `http://www.url.com + $(this)...`? (hope it makes sense, haha!)

Comment: If you are going with HTML5 spec, you can actually include the full path in the id, since the "/" character is a valid character for `id`s under HTML5.

Comment: This solution works once. When I go from `id=page1` to `id=index`, it works fine. When I want to go back to `id=page1` it doesn't do anything. Any idea why?